# How to get the ascii dec number of a keypress in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

In winform, if i wanted to get the ascii code of a key pressed i would do like so:

```
Private void textbox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    int i = e.KeyChar;
}
```

how would i go about doing like so in WPF?
Also, is KeyPress in winforms the equivalent of KeyDown in WPF?

Comment: By `ascii` code you meant int value of enum `Key`?

Comment: @RohitVats Yes, i think? Like the ascii code of 0 is 48

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to capture the `KeyDown` event in WPF as follows:

```
    private void TextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        int ascii = KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(e.Key);
    }
```

Comment: Question was how to get ascii